# How the weight $ω_{i,t}$ is initialized in Background subtraction GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model)?

Tags: image-segmentation, background-subtraction

I read [Chris Stauffer paper "Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking"](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/vsam/Publications/stauffer_cvpr98_track.pdf) about Gaussian Mixture Model for background subtraction, but they're not explained very detail about $ω_{i,t}$ value, what I want to ask is how the value initialized and what the range of it?

Comment: Every time someone is citing the paper it is good practice to include it after all.

Comment: I citing the paper..